# android 4.x with facebook SDK and action bar

Tags: android, facebook, android-actionbar

I'm starting to develop an app with android 4.0 who uses facebook login.

to develop an app with facebook sdk the minimum required sdk it's 2.2 but I need the action bar that uses the minimum required sdk 3, what i should to do for develop an app with facebook sdk and action bar?

Comment: Use [actionbarsherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) library. It provides actionbar support for all versions from 2.x up.

Comment: When I did the action bar with minimum required sdk 2.2 the action bar appears in the botton, when I click the menu button.

and when I try with minimum required sdk 4.0 the action bar appears in the right place, in action bar
and this is the place i want when I try with minimum sdk 2.2

Answer (score 0):

Use AppCompat support library from Google:

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat